# Index a pandas dataframe with a value in one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['idx'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D']
print(df)

          A         B         C idx
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738   A
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278   B
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219   C
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274   D
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863   A
5  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158   B
6  0.313068 -0.854096 -2.552990   C
7  0.653619  0.864436 -0.742165   B
8  2.269755 -1.454366  0.045759   C
9 -0.187184  1.532779  1.469359   D
```

I have a pandas dataframe like above.

I need to create a new column 'value' that for each row, indexes the value in the column in 'idx' if it exists, and returns 'NaN' if it doesn't.

My expected output is:

```
          A         B         C idx     value
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738   A  1.764052
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278   B  1.867558
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219   C -0.103219
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274   D  NaN
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863   A  0.761038
5  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158   B  1.494079
6  0.313068 -0.854096 -2.552990   C -2.552990
7  0.653619  0.864436 -0.742165   B  0.864436
8  2.269755 -1.454366  0.045759   C  0.045759
9 -0.187184  1.532779  1.469359   D  NaN
```

Comment: Have you tried it by yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `isin` to filter out invalid column names, then use `DataFrame.lookup` to, well, ... "lookup" your values.

```
idx = df.loc[df.idx.isin(df.columns), 'idx']
df.loc[idx.index, 'value'] = df.lookup(idx.index, idx)
df

          A         B         C idx     value
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738   A  1.764052
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278   B  1.867558
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219   C -0.103219
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274   D       NaN
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863   A  0.761038
5  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158   B  1.494079
6  0.313068 -0.854096 -2.552990   C -2.552990
7  0.653619  0.864436 -0.742165   B  0.864436
8  2.269755 -1.454366  0.045759   C  0.045759
9 -0.187184  1.532779  1.469359   D       NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Do with

```
df['value']=np.nan

df['value']=df.values[df.index,df.columns.get_indexer(df.idx)]
df
Out[1130]: 
          A         B         C idx     value
0  0.416356 -1.290687 -0.436484   A  0.416356
1  0.600539  1.107413 -0.100904   B   1.10741
2 -0.455892  0.913249  0.294055   C  0.294055
3 -0.545505 -1.120002 -1.649593   D       NaN
4 -0.710129 -1.563575 -0.343713   A -0.710129
5 -0.684759 -0.554275 -0.400649   B -0.554275
6  0.148388 -0.088781  0.445293   C  0.445293
7  0.974738 -0.444588  0.290779   B -0.444588
8  2.346131  0.084158 -0.855563   C -0.855563
9  0.812868 -1.308031  0.605916   D       NaN
```